# What are the possibilities to move objects in memory?

Tags: c++, memory, move, memmove

*Trivially copyable* objects can be moved in memory by `memmove`, such as:

```
struct X { };

int main() {
   static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<X>);

   X* px1 = (X*)operator new(sizeof(X));
   new(px1) X{};

   X* px2 = (X*)operator new(sizeof(X));
   memmove(px2, px1, sizeof(X));
   px2->~X();

   operator delete(px1);
   operator delete(px2);
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/68d1cqMt6yd8LBR4.

I just wonder whether there are some other mechanisms how to move objects in memory (reallocate them) next to `memmove` allowed by the C++ Standards.

---

To make it clear, I am not asking about C++11 move semantics, which does not move anything by itself.

Comment: `std::move` is NOT such a possibility.

Comment: Alloc new memory block, copy old object into it, free memory of old object. The point of `memmove` is that it supports copying from overlapping regions. So in your example `memmove` could be replaced with `memcpy`. All the "moving" here is just memory copying.

Comment: @VTT So is it safe not to call the (trivial) destructor of the old object if it exists in this case?

Comment: You only construct one object so there should be only one destructor invocation.